# can't find google protobuf gem even though it was just installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, protocol-buffers, jekyll, bundle

first of all, I am not using the system ruby, I am using the newly installed, since there are a lot of problems with the system ruby on Mac OS.  `which ruby` and `which gem` both show they are using the same ruby

I am trying to run Jekyll serve but the bundle can't finde google protobuf. I tried `bundle install` and `gem install google-protobuf` but nothing works. the terminal output looks like this:

```
username@MBP repo % gem install google-protobuf
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed google-protobuf-3.25.2
Parsing documentation for google-protobuf-3.25.2
Done installing documentation for google-protobuf after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

username@MBP repo % bundle info google-protobuf-3.25.2   
Could not find gem 'google-protobuf-3.25.2'.

username@MBP repo % bundle exec jekyll serve             
Could not find google-protobuf-3.25.2 in locally installed gems
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

username@MBP repo % jekyll server                        
Ignoring google-protobuf-3.25.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine google-protobuf --version 3.25.2
Ignoring google-protobuf-3.25.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine google-protobuf --version 3.25.2
/Users/jakobimuller/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:570:in `materialize': Could not find google-protobuf-3.25.2 in locally installed gems (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/jakobimuller/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in `specs'
    from /Users/jakobimuller/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:270:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/jakobimuller/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:18:in `setup'
    from /Users/jakobimuller/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:162:in `setup'
    from /Users/jakobimuller/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:52:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /Users/jakobimuller/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jakobimuller/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
    from /Users/jakobimuller/.gem/ruby/3.1.3/bin/jekyll:25:in `<main>'
```

I tried installing it with the script, with `bundle install` and with `gem install` but none properly installed it resulting in me not being able to execute `Jekyll serve`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `gem 'google-protobuf'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`. When you run commands with `bundle` it uses only gems that are specified in project's Gemfile.